# Json data - white console - Xcode 9

Tags: arrays, json, currency, xcode9

I am trying a simple app in which I want to convert some values. It worked until I tried to convert the data in a dictionary,  and when I hit run, it builds successfully, but the console does not print anything. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "http://gnb.dev.airtouchmedia.com/rates.json")
    let task  = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

    if error != nil
         {
        print("ERROR")
    }
    else {
        if let content  = data  {
            do {

                //Array
                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                //print(myJson)

                if let rate  = myJson["rate"] as? NSDictionary {

                    if let currency = rate["AUD"] {
                        print(currency)
                    }
                }
         }
            catch {

            }
        }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are parsing JSON wrongly

try this

```
let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return }
for rate in myJson
    guard let cur = user["from"] as? String,
        let curRate = user["rate"] as? Double else { break }

        if let cur = "AUD" {
            print(curRate)
        }
```

**Update:**

You are receiving Array of Objects in response,

so first you have to treat it as Array of object,

Then you have to loop through this objects and then inside that loop you have to extract the data you were looking for and play with it.

Comment: I did tried it now, but i have a bunch of errors, and i'm trying to handle them now.  Hope it works! Thx!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @mihir-dave. You could improve the answer by explaining what the differences are and why they are critical, so that others finding this answer are able to learn from it.